# Creating a New Web Application project in Google app engine through Eclipse in Mac

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, google-app-engine

I have installed the Google plugin for Eclipse and tried to create a new Web Project. I have followed all the steps mentioned in creating a new web project in developers.google.com and clicked finish. After that I am getting a dialogue box as shown here and it gets stuck in that Auto share Git Projects for hours.: [image]item getting inst

Even Eclipse freezes when I try to close the dialogue box.I tried many times and I am clueless about what steps need to be followed to rectify this. Can you help in resolving this.

Comment: Turn off your internet connection and try again :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that Eclipse tries to connect to GIT and it was not able to establish a connection. I     tried installing GIT for Eclipse and everything goes smoothly after that. Thanks @Martin Berends for giving a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that lack of a known_hosts entry causes the "Auto share git project" to hang.  Git uses ssh by default, and it is possible that your ssh (a text console program) is asking for permission to connect to a not yet known host, probably github.com.  The Eclipse GUI might not show that prompt and hangs waiting for ssh to continue.

Try creating a throwaway project (called librarian for example) to verify your Github account.  Follow this [Github help](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo) and related documentation to use git at the command line.  After your have added github.com to ~/.ssh/known_hosts once for your username, ssh should not prompt again and Eclipse should shell git without hanging.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I cannot resolve the issue still. If you don't mind can you please explain me in detail ?